# failed to open stream error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a anchor

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed/'.urlencode("http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture"),'Tehnology')
```

When i click it redirect me to the getFeed function in the controller:

```
function getFeed($feed_url){
   $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
   $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);}
```

But it gives me this error:file_get_contents(http:): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
and Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML.
 If i put the link (http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture) direct in file_get_contents('http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture') it works but i don't want to do like this because i have 3 anchors with 3 different links.

Comment: check url in getFeed function. `echo $feed_url` before your get content function.

Comment: it shows me only http: why?

Comment: change your url as `site/getFeed/?url=http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture`. Then you can get url as `$this->input->get("url");`

Comment: i put site/getFeed/?url=http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture in the anchor and $this->input->get("url") in file_get_contents and it gives me the same error

Comment: Message: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty and String coul not be parsed as XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better encode your url before passing in url.

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed/'.urlencode("http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture"),'Tehnology');
```

Or:

```
echo anchor('site/getFeed?url='.urlencode("http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture"),'Tehnology');
```

In controller

```
function getFeed()
{
   $feed_url = $this->inout->get("url");
   $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
   $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
}
```

Comment: Message: file_get_contents(site/getFeed/http:/feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: in file_get_contents must appear("http:/feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture") to work

Comment: in controller function what  modify

Comment: i've encode my url and it gives me same error :Message: file_get_contents(site/getFeed/http:/feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: function getFeed($feed_url)
{
    $url =ltrim($this->uri->uri_string(), '/');
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);}

Comment: keep your old code controller. remove lines added from my old answer.

Comment: i've tried this and my error is Message: file_get_contents(http:): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: again check what are you getting in $feed_url. i mean my first comment in question.

Comment: if i echoes i'm getting only http:

Comment: now it gives me this error Message: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty